# Oracle SQL Cast two different columns to one column?

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

I am selecting data from two different columns depending on what sort of record it is.

Using a Case statement I check what type of record it is and select the appropriate column to insert.

However the syntax for using CAST is not correct and after checking the Oracle docs, there is no reason why it is not working.

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST123 AS
SELECT DISTINCT
              bill.ROW_ID,
              bill.ACCNT_TYPE_CD,
              CASE
              WHEN bill.ACCNT_TYPE_CD = 'TestAccount'
              THEN  CAST(TO_CHAR(bill.INTEGRATION_ID) AS VARCHAR2(30)) AS NUM
              ELSE CAST(TO_CHAR(bill.OU_NUM )AS VARCHAR2(30)) AS NUM
              END        
FROM SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT bill
INNER JOIN Products prod
ON prod.BILL_ACCNT_ID = bill.ROW_ID
OR prod.CUST_ACCNT_ID = bill.ROW_ID;
```

Error code is:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AS NUM` must follow the `END` of the `CASE`. If you could set the column name for each condition separately, then the column could have two different names. Clearly that can't work.

```
CASE
WHEN bill.ACCNT_TYPE_CD = 'TestAccount'
THEN  CAST(TO_CHAR(bill.INTEGRATION_ID) AS VARCHAR2(30))
ELSE CAST(TO_CHAR(bill.OU_NUM )AS VARCHAR2(30))
END AS NUM
```

Also, using both `TO_CHAR` and `CAST(... as VARCHAR(30))` is redundant. They are both ways of converting a non-string to a string.

Answer (score 3):

And since `CASE .. END` is a function, you can go even further than explained by *Allan*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
    CAST(
        CASE WHEN bill.ACCNT_TYPE_CD = 'TestAccount'
          THEN bill.INTEGRATION_ID
          ELSE bill.OU_NUM
        END
        AS VARCHAR(30) -- `AS` here is part of the `CAST` function
                       --      and will denote the requested data type
    ) AS NUM           -- `AS` here introduces the column alias
```

<sup>If your not familiar with the `CAST` function, please beware of the double meaning of the `AS` keyword here. See the comments in the code above</sup>